# Multiple levels of semantic zoom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, zooming

Is there a way to do multiple levels of semantic zoom in a C#/XAML app for Windows 8? I am working on a feed reader and I want the user to be able to zoom out from the list of articles and filter the posts by month. The problem is that I have multiple years, so when I zoom out I want to be able to select the year, then at the next level - the month and finally navigate to a page that displays the filtered list. I have already done this, but I only managed to do a single semantic zoom level (the month view). I only need to add the year level.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455775/how-can-used-semantic-zoom-for-3-level-in-uwp/52464082#52464082

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing out of the box, but you can still implement that.
In my opinion, semantic zoom is not very intuitive and discoverable. So multiple level of semantic zoom might be even worse. I wouldn't recommend that kind of interaction.