# How can used semantic zoom for 3 level in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, deepzoom, semantic-zoom

I want to use semantic zoom (or its effect) for selecting a location in my UWP Application.

I want to select the county first, and second select city, and third select the location.

Has anyone a true idea about this?

I searched multiple zooms for semantic zoom, but it's apparently impossible.

I used two semantic zoom parallax, but that has its problems also.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shashankyerramilli/2014/02/14/implementing-a-custom-semantic-zoom-container

from this page, I understood that we can have a Grid in semantic zoom!
I created a semantic zoom and in ZoomedInView add a SemanticGrid (that I've added like above link) and I add another semantic zoom into this SemanticGrid

now I have 3 level zoom and I'm happy :)

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Roshani if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.